# Matlab angle between two points

Tags: matlab, angle, points

I am looking for an algorithm to calculate the angle between two points (defined by x and y valaue) in an image. The angle should be between the horizontal-line of one of these points and the line that connects the two points.

How can I do that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Comment: Rephrased the question to make it less off-topic and more about programming :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) use this:

atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1)

This will return the angle between a horizontal vector from (x1,y1) to (x1+1,y1) and the vector from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2).